# Can I bypass crontab command by putting the file?

Tags: linux, cron, busybox

I need to create and put my cron file with

```
cat cronfile1 cronfile2 > cronfile
crontab cronfile -u myuser
```

This works for me, but I want to know if I can do directly

```
cat cronfile1 cronfile2 > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/myuser
```

Of course I am root, and I'm doing this from busybox. Is it safe or am I doing something wrong and should use the crontab command instead?

Comment: You were missing the `>` operator in your second example. I assume my fix is what you were intending to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `crontab` command so that the daemon notified about the chanage and parse errors can be warned about. It is not advisable to manually write the file.